# SQL/PHP query with ORDER and WHERE

Tags: php, sql

I am having an SQL query problem. I am trying to get data in an ordered fashion between two dates. Here is a simplification of the code I am having problem with:

```
$query = "SELECT Name DateTime FROM table1";
$query .= " ORDER BY DateTime ASC";
$query .= " WHERE DateTime between  date1 AND date2";

$result = mysql_query($query);

//fetch data here
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$output[] = $row;
}
    print(json_encode($output));
```

The code above works when I comment out the line: $query .= " ORDER BY DateTime ASC";

What can I correct so that I can return ordered data between two dates?

EDIT:
When I move ORDER to after WHERE shouldn't  $output now be sorted? I return it to an android application and it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: You also need a comma: `SELECT Name, DateTime`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ORDER BY clause has to come at the end:

```
$query = "SELECT Name DateTime FROM table1";
$query .= " WHERE DateTime between  date1 AND date2";
$query .= " ORDER BY DateTime ASC";
```

The general order for clauses is:

```
SELECT
FROM
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
ORDER BY
```

Comment: +1. As well, the query call should have been written `$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())`, at bare minimum, which would've revealed the syntax error immediately.

Comment: @MarcB: who needs error messages when there's stack overflow? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You query is almost correct, but the `ORDER BY` clause must come after `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

Change it into:

```
$query = "SELECT Name DateTime FROM table1";
$query .= " WHERE DateTime between  date1 AND date2";
$query .= " ORDER BY DateTime ASC";

$result = mysql_query($query);

//fetch data here
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$output[] = $row;
}
    print(json_encode($output));
```

The problem lies within the order of elements in your query: **`ORDER` part should come after `WHERE` part**.

See for example [the documentation of eg. MySQL `SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

```sql
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
    [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
    [INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options
      | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
      | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
    [FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your ORDER BY at the end of the query

```
$query = "SELECT Name, DateTime FROM table1";
$query .= " WHERE DateTime between  date1 AND date2";
$query .= " ORDER BY DateTime ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

You do select with your where condition then order your result. So put order by at the end of the query